# How can I use angular 2 with a not single page website?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular2/typescript but have a few years of experience using angular 1.

I want to use angular 2 in a website which Backend is handling the routing and most of the templates, I just want to add my components to some of the pages. same way that we could use them in angular 1.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is the application using `angular 1.x` currently ?

Comment: I guess with this requirements it's better to stick with AngularJS 1.x.

Comment: No, it is using an old deprecated framework and we are in the process of upgrading it to angular 2